# How to use -complete=lua for command-completion?

Tags: neovim, command-line, lua

If you check the help for `:command-completion`, there is a line that reads:

```
-complete=lua       Lua expression
```

But it does not give further instructions about how to use it, or how to provide a Lua expression. Is it supposed to work like custom,function? Can I inline a Lua expression somehow?  Does it do something else?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, this means that you can complete a Lua variable name (including variables of "function" type).

Or, if you prefer, "tab" completes from a keys list of a Lua table you are currently referencing (starting from the globals `_G` table assumed by default).

Comment: Frankly I'm not sure it's obvious at all. Similar lines like `-complete=custom,{func} custom completion, defined via {func}` and `-complete=var  user variables` are either _not_ a variable name, or indicate where a variable should be and what it is, etc. The quoted line in the OP is vague at best.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble There are "var" and "expression" that complete in VimScript variables and both var/funcs names respectively. In Lua all functions are variables by definition, so there's only a single completion "lua" instead of two. If you believe there's a need for better explanation in docs, you can propose a PR to Neovim project.

Comment: I see now—I think the misunderstanding you are pointing to in your answer was itself unclear. It seems you mean to say something like "`-complete=lua` does not offer a way to _use_ lua for completion (see `-complete=custom`). Instead, it _completes_ the names of lua variables, much like how `-complete=var` completes vimscript variables."

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I'm probably very bad in explaining in foreign language, as this is exactly what I'm trying to explain for a few days. `-complete=lua` completes Lua variable names. While custom completion in Lua is as simple as `-complete=custom,v:lua.MyLuaCompletionFunc`. So there's no need to re-invent custom completion for Lua specifically. What makes people even consider this?

Comment: Like I said, I think I'm following now. I don't know the reason for the OP's confusion, but mine was something like "everyone wants to put everything in Lua [this seems misguided], so having a completion that uses lua specifically might make sense, and this is the only part of the docs that mention it." That said, I don't use NeoVim, so I was also probably led astray by trying to compare the quoted docs with the vim docs :P

Comment: I follow what's been explained in the comments, but I think a fuller example in the answer would go a long way toward helping folks be less confused by this.

Comment: As many mentioned already, I don't think this is obvious at all, and that's why I opened this issue, same things are not obvious for everybody. Even after reading this answer it was not clear to me what to use it for until someone else pointed out what it actually means in the comments. I was looking for a way to execute lua functions as auto-complete function callback, because lua is what I'm familiar with. If  you think that `-complete=custom,v:lua.MyFN` is something everybody should came as a conclusion, I suggest you review your definition of obvious, because that is anything but obvious.

Comment: @Danielo515 This is basic. And if "basic" is anything but "obvious" then you need to learn "how do I use help" again. That is, type `:h lua` then press `gO` and browse through the contents table.